# Which aspect of MouseEvent, or something else, triggers visual highlighting?

Tags: javascript, mouseevent, highlighting, textselection

The title manages to ask most of the question, however, I'm curious which part of using the LMB to click triggers the visual highlighting.

What I mean by visual highlighting is the blue colored box (if you are on default) that shows what text you have selected, so you can see it. To my knowledge, the actual selection is a difference of the selection objects anchor and focus, but is there something somewhere in between that tells Chrome to draw a blue box?

I figure these two things, text selection and text highlighting, aren't necessarily working together but rather working simultaneously. I would love to be able to simulate text selection - and thus highlighting - with other keys/buttons.

Answer (score 0):

If i understood your question you talking about .select event(i'll use jquery to show what you can do with that). that event trigged when user select some text in your element. for example:

```
$("#TextArea").on("select", function(){
    alert("you have been selected somesing");
});
```

TextArea is an textarea of course.

**EDIT**: just some more info, and tips:

```
$("#TextArea").on("select", function(){
    indexOfSelectionStart = this.selectionStart;
    indexOfSelectionEnd = this.selectionEnd;
    alert("first index: " + indexOfSelectionStart + ". sec: "indexOfSelectionEnd);
});
```

With the indexes you can know what the user has selected(if you use [slice()](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_slice_array.asp))

I hope that helped, let me know if not.

Good Luck.

Comment: Sort of interesting information and quite useful, but it doesn't answer the question.

What I'm trying to do is recreate highlight, not text selection. In other words, I want to create the blue box that appears around text when you've selected text.

Comment: is it text in textbox/textarea or just normal text? you can use CSS to highlight specific element(div, p, a etc). but i'm still not sure if that what you want

Comment: No, technically it's text within <body>, so most, if not all of the text on this screen.

How would you highlight "dynamically" (drawing custom highlight starts and ends) using CSS?